# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

I am referring to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.14393.0\ WDK files. Though I have installed latest 10.0.15063.0. It seems some files are missing in 10.0.14393 folder.

Anyone could help me to in this. Reparing Microsoft Visual Studio15 or reparing wdk 10.0.15063 does not help.

Comment: ctype.h is a compiler include file, not part of the SDK or WDK.  For VS2015 and up it is part of the Universal CRT, a typical install location would be C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10249.0\ucrt.  Project > Properties > VC++ Directories > Include Directories setting.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have installed "Universal CRT" component of your visual studio.

**More over for newer versions of Visual studio**
in case the directory "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits" exists on your system ensure that it contains "10/Include" and "10/Lib" subdirectories.
If not create hard links there to thoose present in your "C:\Program Files **(x86)**\Windows Kits\10"

As you can see from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\uCRT.props
the path "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits" is prefered over "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits" if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio go to *Project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories* and add:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt**

In *Project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories*  add:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64**

That's it, your program should now compile without errors!

Comment: Why is it this way?  I just did a clean VS install on a new OBE Windows 11, and got this and have never seen it before. And you are right, its missing from the 64 bit Program Files location