# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../include/ctype.h': No such file or directory Visual Studio 2017 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I tried to compile an old project but I always see these errors. I tried to retarget my project, change included directories or repairing visual studio but any of them did not work for me.
[image: ctype.h class]
[image: errors output (there is backslash problem but it does not effect the probem. I tried to change my locale to may be a solution for errors but there were nothing changed when ı change my locale and fixed bvackslahes))]
when ı tried to open the project solution in visual studio 2017, visual studio 2017 wants to upgrade my project because project was created in an older version of visual studio (probably 2005).
[image: upgrade warming]

is there anyone who has some suggestion about these errors ?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: probably targetting a non-existent windows SDK version

Comment: The comments in the file indicate that it is a workaround for handling 'embedded Visual C++'. Since you aren't using that compiler I guess the best option would be to delete that file, and redirect any include of the file to the standard equivalent (presumably that would be `#include <ctype.h>`).

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Comment: Hi, I tried all the solution combinations but ı could not solve it in vs 17 or 22. finally,  ı decided to build the code in vs 2005 and it worked :d. thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to download Windows 10 SDK in visual studio installer.

[image]

Then set the Windows SDK version to 10 in the project properties.

[image]

Also, the method in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47051867/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-ctype-h-no-such-file-or-director) is also worth referencing.